# How to access state set through a function which is called in ComponentDidMount()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function called `calendarLogicHandler()` which sets `state`, spreading a whole month into it. I called it inside `componentDidMount()`.

the `state` set works on the calendar `app` which I am working on. This calendar tool will be part of a yoga classes `app`.

then on the week View Mode of the tool, which displays all of events of a single week, I call `weekAgendaLogicHandler()`, which filters the current week of the current month and displays it on the `app`. The `state` for the current week and current month are manipulated further ahead in my logic, but there is no point in displaying this here.

The issue is:

I cannot access `this.state.currrentMonth` on `ComponentDidMount()` and somehow I see that when I try to `console.log(this.state.currentMonth)` on `render()` I see that it renders `this.state.currentMonth` twice blank, then, on the third re-rendering it finally gets the `this.state.currentMonth` set by `calendarLogicHandler()`.

```
current month in render() []
current month in render() []
getting current month in componentDidMount []
current month in render() [Array[7], Array[7], Array[7], Array[7], Array[7]]
current month in render() [Array[7], Array[7], Array[7], Array[7], Array[7]]
[]
```

How could I properly use this function so I can call `weekAgendaLogicHandler()` without having it called inside the `callback` `function` of `this.setState({currentMonth})`, and setting my state before the rendering phase, in other words, before `componentdidmount`?

the code is [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/testing-componentdidmount-p0wf9?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) and below:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    currentWeek: [],
    currentMonth: [],
    monthGetter: new Date().getMonth(),
    yearGetter: new Date().getFullYear()
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.calendarLogicHandler();
    this.weekAgendaLogicHandler();
    console.log(
      "getting current month in componentDidMount",
      this.state.currentMonth
    );
  }

  weekAgendaLogicHandler = () => {
    let currentWeek = this.state.currentMonth
      .filter(week => week.includes(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)))
      .flat();
    this.setState({ currentWeek }, () => console.log(this.state.currentWeek));
  };

  calendarLogicHandler = () => {
    const oneDay = 86400000;
    const lastDayOfTheMonth = new Date(
      this.state.yearGetter,
      this.state.monthGetter + 1,
      0
    ).getDate();
    let currentMonth = [
      new Date(this.state.yearGetter, this.state.monthGetter, 1).valueOf()
    ]; //starts on month day 1
    for (let i = 1; i < lastDayOfTheMonth; i++) {
      //push the entire month
      currentMonth.push(Math.max.apply(null, currentMonth) + oneDay);
    }
    //localize the first date of the month dates array and check what day of the week it is
    //spread the days of the week, which are the remaining days of prev month to fill calendar first week
    for (let i = new Date(Math.min(...currentMonth)).getDay(); i > 0; i--) {
      currentMonth.unshift(Math.min.apply(null, currentMonth) - oneDay);
    }
    //spread the days of the week, which are the remaining days of prev month to fill calendar last week
    for (let i = new Date(Math.max(...currentMonth)).getDay(); i < 6; i++) {
      currentMonth.push(Math.max.apply(null, currentMonth) + oneDay);
    }
    let monthInWeeks = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < currentMonth.length; i += 7) {
      let chunk = currentMonth.slice(i, i + 7);
      monthInWeeks.push(chunk);
    }
    currentMonth = monthInWeeks;
    this.setState({ currentMonth });
  };

  render() {
    console.log("current month in render()", this.state.currentMonth);
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Testing componentDidMount</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure that I understand what do you want to accomplish? Maybe to see how state looks like after `this.calendarLogicHandler(); this.weekAgendaLogicHandler();`?

If that is the case use `componentDidUpdate`. In `componentDidMount` you can only see how state looks like at the time component get mounted in the dom.

So it doesn't matter that you are doing `console.log` in this order:

```
this.calendarLogicHandler();
this.weekAgendaLogicHandler();
console.log(
  "getting current month in componentDidMount",
  this.state.currentMonth
);
```

... you are still logging the state as it was before `calendarLogicHandler` & `weekAgendaLogicHandler` are fired.

### Update:

If you don't wan't to call `weekAgendaLogicHandler` in `componentDidMount` (because you don't already have state in shape you need), than you can use something like this:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
 if(/* check that state is previously updated by `calendarLogicHandler` */) {
  this.weekAgendaLogicHandler();
 }
}
```

But, using a lot timing (hooking into lifecycle events) can make your code unnecessary complex. If I were you, would choose to use `setState` callback to call `this.weekAgendaLogicHandler()`;

Comment: ```this.weekAgendaLogicHandler()``` mounts the calendar when the component renders. Then I manipulate it using other functions, moving the months ahead and backwards. I have placed ```console logs``` in my logic just to exemplify the issue. The deal is that I need to access ```this.state.currentMonth``` immediately so I also render the week inside the week view mode of the app. And this is not possible if I call ```this.weekAgendaLogicHandler()``` inside ```componentDidMount()``` as well, as ```state``` is not available there yet  . I wanna overcome this

Comment: Have updated my answer. Kindly let me know if it answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for your update! Based in my logic idea, If set my current week in the ```callback function``` inside ```calendarLogicHandler``` the app would break if I tried to increment the weeks, as the ```component``` would mount again and send my week back to the initial week, which is the current week in time and space.

Comment: let me try and implement your solution

Comment: OK. When updating state, component doesn't unmount and mount again. It just re-render. You won't be loosing updated state if you use `setState callback` (i.e. state won't go to initial state). React keeps state in memory (due closures).

Comment: it did solve my state issue! Thanks @Danko https://codesandbox.io/embed/testing-componentdidmount-u0z9n?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 2):

This is the way how react works.

Lifecycle `render()` method gets called on every update. And also it gets called before `componentDidMount` . According to the lifecycle name `componentDidMount` means function getting called after component got mounted. And since component got already `mounted`, so `render()` method already got called before `componentDidMount` method.

So, first time when you are getting blank data i.e, before `componentDidMount` , `render()` is getting called with the initial state ie, `[]`

Second time again, probably something is getting updated probably in `weekAgendaLogicHandler()` function due to which again `render()` is getting called with blank `[]` array ie., the initial state.

Now, third time , this.setState is happening state is getting updated and then on `render()` you are getting the required array.

So, this is how `render()` lifecycle method works.

Now, if you want to use `render` only with the data and not `null` data. Then , you can show some kind of loader.

i.e,

```
render(){
  if(this.state.currentMonth.length){
    return(
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Testing componentDidMount</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
  else{
    return(
      <p>Loading data...</p>
     )
   }
}
```

Comment: The point is that I need to run ```this.weekAgendaLogicHandler()``` to spread the current week, accessing ```this.state.currenMonth```. If I place this logic inside ```render()``` I will break the ```app``` leading to an infinite number of ```setState```. I made it work using ```componentDidUpdate()```. Still implementing the logic to navigate through weeks, incrementing and decrementing, but so far so good.